# Routing jQuery and Cache (M/Mumps) based html pages and React.js pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, url-routing

I'm working for a company right now and for their whole website they use Cache (language) to 'spit' out HTML onto the page to be rendered then JavaScript and jQuery (and CSS) is used for other things from there.

I've learned React and have been writing Components that I want to use and learned react-router to do my client side routing for me.

I don't know how to integrate the routing part of the webpage (the code essentially) that has been already created with Cache and JavaScript with the new React pages and react-router

The company has no routing whatsoever right now. It is a bunch of iframes like a tree type structure with  links so I really need to get it converted to a routing sort of setup.

Sorry It's so long, but now is my question:

Would I use a Node.js webserver and Express.js for the routing for the already build Cache/JavaScrip pages and then once I get that taken care of start using react-router from there to take care of all the new React Components?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at EWD 3:

https://community.intersystems.com/post/announcing-ewd-3-integrating-javascript-nodejs-and-cache-communities

Also look for the postings in this forum on EWD 3 and React.js (and React Native):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/enterprise-web-developer-community

Comment: please explain the answer in the post and link the websites only to support your response